# Pandas join memoryError

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

I'm trying to join 2 dataframes, essentially trying to replicate a vlookup in python. 
The command I'm running is

```
df_Eligible_w_Hier = df_Eligible.join(df_ProdHier, on='Sku', how='left',lsuffix='_ProdHier')
```

df_Eligible has 13949037 rows and df_ProdHier has 31897.

I'm using a Win7 core i5 with 4Gb of memory.

I keep getting a MemoryError, is that normal. Those df don't seem that big to me. How can I solve or work around this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running 32 or 64-bit version of python?

Comment: platform.architecture()
('32bit', 'WindowsPE')

Comment: I don't know if it should run out of memory or not but I would try with 64-bit python to see it works.

Comment: I suspect this depends on how many rows share a sku number (as this can explode - i.e. if 2 rows join with two rows then you get 4 rows etc.)

Comment: each sku corresponds to one row in df_ProdHier and several hundred rows in df_Eligible